# adding two columns from a data frame in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I have two columns age and salary stored in DF. I just want to write a scala code to add these values column wise. i tried

```
val age_1 = df.select("age")
val salary_1=df.select("salary")
val add = age_1+salary_1
```

gives me error.  please help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the following `spark` is an instance of `SparkSession`, so the import has to come *after* the instantiation of `spark`.

**$-notation** can be used here by importing spark implicits  with

```
import spark.implicits._
```

then use $-notation

```
val add = df.select($"age" + $"salary")
```

**final scala code:**

```
import spark.implicits._
val add = df.select($"age" + $"salary")
```

[Apache doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#untyped-dataset-operations-aka-dataframe-operations)